# My jQuery code is not kicking off in DisplayForm in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, display-form

I have added some jQuery code to the DisplayForm as follow-

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

function Execute_Attachments_Processing(){
  jQuery('table#idAttachmentsTable td a').each(function(){
    var $parent = jQuery(this).parent();

    var a_src = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    var a_text = jQuery(this).text();

    if(a_src.contains('jpg') || a_src.contains('jpeg') || a_src.contains('png') || a_src.contains('gif')){
      jQuery(this).remove();
      $parent.append('<div style="text-align:center; padding-bottom:20px;"><a target="_blank" href="'+a_src+'"><img title="'+a_text+'" src="'+a_src+'" width="300px" /><br/>'+ a_text+'</a></div>');
    }
  });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    Execute_Attachments_Processing();
});
</script>

// Other html/xml code here..

</content>
```

It converts attachments into viewable images.

It is not executing at all. What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you check is there any script error in the browser console?

Comment: No script error. It works fine in Firebug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(window).load(function() {});` instead of `document.ready()`. It seems your DOM is loading after you are calling the function.

`window.load` will run after all DOM has been loaded completely.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push` method instead of jQuery's `document.ready()`, read [this](http://www.stephanrocks.com/2011/10/05/_spbodyonloadfunctionnames-in-sharepoint-vs-jquerys-document-ready/) article.

Also, [other functions available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936250/sharepoint-2013-add-javascript-after-whole-page-load).

Comment: Followed it. Still no luck.

Comment: Is your jQuery called? Do you see any errors in Console?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SharePoint 2013/Office 365 check if minimum download strategy is enabled for the site. Disable it and have a try.